# web service communication between Jboss 6.2 and 8.2 in the same box

Tags: web-services

I deployed a web service application in WildFly 8.2 version and my another application (name:rapid) in jboss 6.2. Both server are running in the same box.

I can able to connect checkConnection() method in the web service application from my localhost and SOAP UI etc.. and able to get the response. But the same checkConnection() unable to connect from jboss 6.2.

Can any one please help me how to resolve this issue. Is there any configuration changes are required in jboss 6.2 ?  I deployed the same ear in my local jboss and Test server jboss. Every thing working fine from local and not working from TEST server.

I am getting the below error :

```
08:26:42,785 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4) javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
08:26:42,787 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:146)
08:26:42,788 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.checkConnection(Unknown Source)
08:26:42,790 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.deloitte.modeShapeIntegration.service.impl.ModeshapeSearchService.getSearchResults(ModeshapeSearchService.java:255)
08:26:42,791 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.deloitte.modeShapeIntegration.service.impl.ModeshapeSearchService.findRelatedDocumentsFor(ModeshapeSearchService.java:196)
08:26:42,793 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.deloitte.rapid.service.DocumentService.findRelatedDocumentsFor(DocumentService.java:754)
08:26:42,794 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.deloitte.rapid.action.PlanDocumentAction.executeDisplayDocuments(PlanDocumentAction.java:455)
08:26:42,796 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
08:26:42,797 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
08:26:42,799 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
08:26:42,800 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
08:26:42,801 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
08:26:42,803 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
08:26:42,804 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
08:26:42,806 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
08:26:42,807 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,808 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
08:26:42,810 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
08:26:42,812 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,813 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
08:26:42,815 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
08:26:42,816 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
08:26:42,817 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,818 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
08:26:42,820 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,821 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
08:26:42,822 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
08:26:42,824 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,825 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
08:26:42,826 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
08:26:42,828 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,829 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
08:26:42,830 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,831 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
08:26:42,833 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,834 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
08:26:42,835 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,837 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
08:26:42,838 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,844 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
08:26:42,845 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,847 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
08:26:42,848 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,849 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
08:26:42,851 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,852 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
08:26:42,853 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
08:26:42,856 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,858 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
08:26:42,860 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,861 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
08:26:42,862 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,864 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
08:26:42,865 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,866 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
08:26:42,867 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,869 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.deloitte.rapid.action.PostLoginInterceptor.intercept(PostLoginInterceptor.java:115)
08:26:42,870 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,875 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.deloitte.rapid.action.RapidSecurityInterceptor.intercept(RapidSecurityInterceptor.java:42)
08:26:42,880 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
08:26:42,882 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
08:26:42,887 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
08:26:42,888 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
08:26:42,889 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
08:26:42,892 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
08:26:42,894 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
08:26:42,899 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
08:26:42,900 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
08:26:42,905 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:499)
08:26:42,908 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
08:26:42,912 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
08:26:42,914 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
08:26:42,915 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
08:26:42,917 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
08:26:42,920 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
08:26:42,923 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
08:26:42,924 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
08:26:42,930 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
08:26:42,933 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: ConnectException invoking http://ussltcsnl3123.solutions.glbsnet.com:9060/ModeShapeWS/ModeShapeUpload: Connection timed out
08:26:42,938 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
08:26:42,939 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
08:26:42,940 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
08:26:42,944 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
08:26:42,945 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1338)
08:26:42,946 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1322)
08:26:42,948 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
08:26:42,949 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
08:26:42,951 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
08:26:42,953 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
08:26:42,954 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
08:26:42,955 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
08:26:42,956 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
08:26:42,957 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
08:26:42,958 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
08:26:42,960 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
08:26:42,961 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      ... 76 more
08:26:42,969 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
08:26:42,970 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
08:26:42,971 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
08:26:42,972 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
08:26:42,975 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
08:26:42,978 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
08:26:42,980 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
08:26:42,982 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
08:26:42,993 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:484)
08:26:42,997 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:482)
08:26:42,998 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
08:26:42,999 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:481)
08:26:43,000 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:522)
08:26:43,003 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
08:26:43,009 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
08:26:43,010 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
08:26:43,015 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
08:26:43,018 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:975)
08:26:43,027 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
08:26:43,028 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
08:26:43,032 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4)      at
```

Comment: If both services are deployed on the same machine, why aren't you using "localhost" to connect to the other service, instead of the http://ussltcsnl3123.solutions.glbsnet.com you're using now? Depending on your setup, using the name may not be permitted, or may require a trip to a device that your machine doesn't have access to

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may have a firewall in the Test server. Would you able to telnet on the port 9060 from the same box ?

Comment: We disabled all the firewalls on test server. We can able telenet wsdl on 9060 port.